# How do I understand where is my bug when I get a SIGABRT error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm really new to iOS dev (and programming in general), and I would appreciate if you can explain when I get a SIGABRT error, what should I look into to go and fix?

I made a segue from a table view controller to another view controller and when I tap on a cell to preform the segue I get this:

This is the entire console:

```
2014-04-05 00:12:21.832 Robonote[20893:70b] -[UITableViewCell content]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8acb5a0
2014-04-05 00:12:21.874 Robonote[20893:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell content]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8acb5a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0173d5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014c08b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017da903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0172d90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0172d4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   Robonote                            0x00003d3f -[NMNotesListViewController prepareForSegue:sender:] + 287
    6   UIKit                               0x0076306c -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 156
    7   UIKit                               0x007630f9 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
    8   UIKit                               0x00310775 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1453
    9   UIKit                               0x00310924 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 279
    10  UIKit                               0x00314908 __38-[UITableView touchesEnded:withEvent:]_block_invoke + 43
    11  UIKit                               0x0024b183 ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke + 15
    12  UIKit                               0x0024b12e _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 403
    13  UIKit                               0x0024af5a _afterCACommitHandler + 532
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x017054ce __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0170541f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x016e3344 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x016e2ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x016e28db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x036e29e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x036e2809 GSEventRun + 104
    21  UIKit                               0x0022ed3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    22  Robonote                            0x0000357d main + 141
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d7b701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

This is the NMNotesListViewController.m :

```
    import "NMNotesListViewController.h"
    #import "NMCreateNotesViewController.h"

    @interface NMNotesListViewController ()

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *notes;

    @end

    @implementation NMNotesListViewController



    - (IBAction) unwindToList: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue
    {

        NMCreateNotesViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
        NMNote *note = source.note;

        if (note != nil) {
            [self.notes addObject:note];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }

    }

    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.notes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return [self.notes count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NotesPrototypeCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Configure the cell...


        NMNote *note = [self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = note.content;


        return cell;
    }


    - (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UITableViewCell *)sender

    {
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"noteSegue"]) {
            NMCreateNotesViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
            NSInteger indx = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender].row;
            NMNote *note = self.notes[indx];
            destination.passedInString = note.content;
        }
    }


//#pragma mark - delegate
//
//- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//{
//    
//}

@end
```

And this is the NMCreateNotesViewController.m :

```
 #import "NMCreateNotesViewController.h"
#import "NMNotesListViewController.h"


@interface NMCreateNotesViewController () <UITextViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;



@end



@implementation NMCreateNotesViewController


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // listen for keyboard hide/show notifications so we can properly adjust the table's height
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}


#pragma mark - Notifications


- (void)adjustViewForKeyboardReveal:(BOOL)showKeyboard notificationInfo:(NSDictionary *)notificationInfo
{
    // the keyboard is showing so ƒ the table's height
    CGRect keyboardRect = [[notificationInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration =
    [[notificationInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect frame = self.textField.frame;

    // the keyboard rect's width and height are reversed in landscape
    NSInteger adjustDelta = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation) ? CGRectGetHeight(keyboardRect) : CGRectGetWidth(keyboardRect);

    if (showKeyboard)
        frame.size.height -= adjustDelta;
    else
        frame.size.height += adjustDelta;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    self.textField.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}



- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self adjustViewForKeyboardReveal:YES notificationInfo:[aNotification userInfo]];
}



- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self adjustViewForKeyboardReveal:NO notificationInfo:[aNotification userInfo]];
}



- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.saveButton) return;
    if (self.textField.text.length > 0) {
        self.note = [[NMNote alloc] init];
        self.note.content = self.textField.text;

    }
}



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (self.passedInString != nil) {
        self.textField.text = self.passedInString;
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: On the right-hand side of your debugger (the console output window), if you scroll up there should be more to that stack trace. Can you post the entire thing here?

Comment: @CraigOtis sure. done :)

Comment: can you post your `[NMNotesListViewController prepareForSegue:sender:]` implementation? Seems link you're calling `content` an a object that's a `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: I would recommend going through the following tutorials understand these error and how to use debugger 

[http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1]
[http://www.raywenderlich.com/28289/debugging-ios-apps-in-xcode-4-5]

Comment: You have your segue in your storyboard, right? To what action is it triggered? `Manual`, `Cell Selection` or `Accessory`?

Comment: @lootsch cell selection, how can i check it to be sure? cause I control dragged the segue from the cell to the other view controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in how you access the note you want to pass,

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"noteSegue"]) {
        NMCreateNotesViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
        NMNote *note = (NMNote*) sender;
        destination.textField.text = note.content;
    }
}
```

This should be,

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UITableViewCell *)sender

{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"noteSegue"]) {
        NMCreateNotesViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSInteger indx = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender].row;
        NMNote *note = self.notes[indx];
        destination.passedInString = note.content;
    }
}
```

Another problem you have is trying to set the value of a textField in the destination view controller from prepareForSegue. You can't do this because that controller's view hasn't been loaded yet, so its outlets will be nil. Instead, create a string property (I called it passedInString) in NMCreateNotesViewController, and use it to set the text field's text in the viewDidLoad method.

If your segue is connected from the cell to the next controller, then you shouldn't be calling performSegueWithIdentifier: in code. In fact, you don't need to implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath: at all.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, it worked :) but now the problem that when I edit a note and clicking save, it saves a new note with the content of the edited one and keeping the one I wanted edited the same :/ i'm pretty sure it got something to do with the code implemented in NMCreateNotesViewController...i'm using there the content property as well and not sure how to populate al the action with passedInString I adde..please help me to solve it @rdelmar

Comment: I also added @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *passedInString;
in the NMCreateNotesViewController.h file

Comment: @user3412425, If you want to edit the note, then you should pass in the NMNote object rather than just its content property. But that's a different problem, so you should post a new question for that.

Comment: just posted a new question :) http://stackoverflow.com/q/22874470/3412425 thanks a lot @rdelmar

Answer (score 2):

First two lines of your console output tells you everything...

```
2014-04-05 00:12:21.832 Robonote[20893:70b] -[UITableViewCell content]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8acb5a0
2014-04-05 00:12:21.874 Robonote[20893:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell content]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8acb5a0'
```

It looks like you are calling `content` method on `UITableviewCell` but this method isn't declarated anywhere. Try inspecting your code (view controller with `UITableView` inside) and find line where `[UITableViewCell content]` method is called.

---

And he got it... In your `NMCreateNotesViewController` there isn't any `contet` method but you're calling it in `prepareForSegue:sender:` method.

Comment: Hi, content is an nsstring property on my NMNots class that holds the note content, it's in the header file of the view controller i'm trying to prefer to (the destination). and I have used this property before and had no problems :/

Comment: @Cojoj You're right. I think it's when he converts `sender` to a note, when it's probably a cell: `NMNote *note = (NMNote*) sender;` He then uses `note.content` on the next line.

Comment: @CraigOtis so this casting is not valid you think..?

Comment: I've edited my answer... @user3412425, declare `- (NSString *)content;` in `NMCreateNotesViewController` header file.

Comment: i think the problem is, that the segue gets fired automatically, with the selected cell as `sender` (that will crash this function), and would be fired again, when he's calling it inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: hi, i have @property (strong, nonatomic) NMNote *note;
 in my NMCreateNotesViewController , and a note have an NSString property called content

Comment: do you want me to publish both the table view controller .m and the view controller .m files? its really short

Comment: The sender argument in prepareForSegue will be the cell, not an NMNote object. That's what the error is telling you.

Comment: @rdelmar but he is casting it to `NMNote`

Comment: @rdelmar I posted the 2 controllers .m files to the question, maybe you can tell me what do you think is best to solve it, thanks

Comment: @Cojoj, casting doesn't change what something is -- it's just telling the compiler what you think the object is. I can call my a cat a dog, but it doesn't make her one.

Comment: @Cojoj i published the .m files of the controller

Comment: @lootsch  i published the .m files of the controllers

Comment: @user3412425 if you use storyboard and have connectd `UITableViewCell` with `NMCreateNotesViewController.m` you don't have to `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"noteSegue" sender:note];`. It's done for you automatically.