# How to pass an object in a segue rather that a detail of an object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a simple notes app where I have just 2 view controllers:

1. table view controller - to list all the notes.
2. view controller - to create new notes.

In the table view controller I have a segue from a cell back to the creation page where a user can edit the note in this specific cell.

But my problem is that when I'm preforming editing to a certain cell(note) I'm creating a new note with the content of what I edited...

So instead of passing the note content in the prepareForSegue method I need to pass the note object...

How can I do that?

this are my classes:

NMNote: (correctly just containing a property of *content, will add more behaviour later)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NMNote : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *content;


@end
```

NMCreateNotesViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NMNote.h"

@interface NMCreateNotesViewController : UIViewController 

@property (strong, nonatomic) NMNote *note;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textField;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *passedInString;


@end
```

NMCreateNotesViewController.m:

```
#import "NMCreateNotesViewController.h"
#import "NMNotesListViewController.h"


@interface NMCreateNotesViewController () <UITextViewDelegate>


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;


@end



@implementation NMCreateNotesViewController


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // listen for keyboard hide/show notifications so we can properly adjust the table's height
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}


#pragma mark - Notifications


- (void)adjustViewForKeyboardReveal:(BOOL)showKeyboard notificationInfo:(NSDictionary *)notificationInfo
{
    // the keyboard is showing so ƒ the table's height
    CGRect keyboardRect = [[notificationInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration =
    [[notificationInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect frame = self.textField.frame;

    // the keyboard rect's width and height are reversed in landscape
    NSInteger adjustDelta = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation) ? CGRectGetHeight(keyboardRect) : CGRectGetWidth(keyboardRect);

    if (showKeyboard)
        frame.size.height -= adjustDelta;
    else
        frame.size.height += adjustDelta;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    self.textField.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}



- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self adjustViewForKeyboardReveal:YES notificationInfo:[aNotification userInfo]];
}



- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self adjustViewForKeyboardReveal:NO notificationInfo:[aNotification userInfo]];
}



- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.saveButton) return;
    if (self.textField.text.length > 0) {
        self.note = [[NMNote alloc] init];
        self.note.content = self.textField.text;

    }
}



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (self.passedInString != nil) {
        self.textField.text = self.passedInString;
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

NMNotesListViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NMNotesListViewController : UITableViewController

- (IBAction) unwindToList: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue;

@end
```

NMNotesListViewController.m:

```
#import "NMNotesListViewController.h"
#import "NMCreateNotesViewController.h"

@interface NMNotesListViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *notes;

@end

@implementation NMNotesListViewController



- (IBAction) unwindToList: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue
{

    NMCreateNotesViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    NMNote *note = source.note;

    if (note != nil) {
        [self.notes addObject:note];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.notes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.notes count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NotesPrototypeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...


    NMNote *note = [self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = note.content;


    return cell;
}


- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UITableViewCell *)sender

{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"noteSegue"]) {
        NMCreateNotesViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSInteger indx = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender].row;
        NMNote *note = self.notes[indx];
        destination.passedInString = note.content;
    }
}

//#pragma mark - delegate
//
//- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//{
//    
//}

@end
```

This is the screens flow:

the initiate view is this table view:

[image]

Now there is the TextView where you write the note:

[image]

Now, after you save a note, you go back to the first screen. and then you can tap on a populated cell and you will segue back to this screen (the one with the TextView) so you can edit it. But instead of editing it, it will create a new one with the edited content. like this:

[image]

Please, would appreciate any help here to accomplish my task..
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should narrow down your code a bit where it's more relevant to the problem, not a lot of people want to sift through all that.

Comment: @JMarsh sorry. I just wanted to give the people enough information to help...I did it because I though it's short, sorry buddy.

Comment: @user3412425 where do you save the note?

Comment: @meda in the NMNotesListViewController I declared an NSMutableArray of notes

Comment: Not sure where your problem in understanding is. Passing an object, any object, whether that be an NSString or your NMNote object is the same. You create a property in the receiving controller that's of the class of your passed in object, then set the value of that property when you create an instance of the receiving controller. The only difference is that you need to import the header file for your custom object whereas you don't for a Foundation or IOKit object (and that's only because they've already been imported in the Prefix.pch file)

Comment: @rdelmar hi, I understand what you said here. but since i'm fairly new to programming i'm still trying to figure out some stuff...like how do I only populate the cell with the content I saved in the create note page, without creating a new one. I did create a boolean newNote var to let the view controller know if the segue that is about to preform is a newNot or not. but if its now, i'm trying to figure out how to populate the cell with the new content but for the same cell..

Comment: I'm a little unsure exactly what you're trying to do. Are you using the NMCreateNotesViewController to both create new notes, and to edit existing ones? If so, how do you add a new note -- I don't see how you're going from the NotesListViewController to the NMCreateNotesViewController without selecting a cell (which you would want to do if you're creating a new note). Also, which controller is the initial controller?

Comment: @rdelmar hi, I added some flow screens that probably will help you understand it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you need to do when you pass the note to the NMCreateNotesViewController, is to differentiate between an edit and an add action so when you came back to the table view, you can either replace the old entry with the new edited one, or add a new entry.

The way I would approach this is to have two segues, one from the + button (I'll call it "addSegue") and one from the table view cell (call it "editSegue"). I would also create a property in the list controller to hold the value of the edited row, or set it to something like -1 to indicate it's a new note. Something like this,

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger editedRow;

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"editSegue"]) {
        NMCreateNotesViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSInteger indx = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)sender].row;
        self.editedRow = index;
        NMNote *note = self.notes[indx];
        destination.note = note;
    }else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addSegue"]) {
        self.editedRow = -1;
}
```

The prepareForSegue method in the NMCreateNotesViewController would be the same as you have in your question. You can get rid of the passedInString property since we're passing in the entire note object instead. In the unwind method in the list controller, you would do this,

```
- (IBAction) unwindToList: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue {

    NMCreateNotesViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    NMNote *note = source.note;

    if (note != nil && self.editedRow == -1) {
        [self.notes addObject:note];
    }else{
        [self.notes replaceObjectAtIndex:self.editedRow withObject:note];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: you have done it again, best answer ever :))) it works perfect and explained me many things along the way! thank you @rdelmar

Answer (score 0):

in NMCreateNotesViewController.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NMNote *note;
@property BOOL adding;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *originalContent;
```

Then in your NMNotesListViewController.m `prepareForSegue`

```
destination.note=self.notes[indx];
destination.adding=NO;            // set adding to yes if you are adding a new note
```

and in your unwind

```
- (IBAction) unwindToList: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue
{

    NMCreateNotesViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    NMNote *note = source.note;

    if (source.adding && note != nil) {
        [self.notes addObject:note];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

}
```

in NMCreateNotesViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // listen for keyboard hide/show notifications so we can properly adjust the table's height
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];

    if (self.note != nil)
    {
        self.originalContent=self.note.content;
        self.textField.text=self.note.content;
    }
}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.saveButton)
    {
        if (self.note != nil)
        {
           self.note.content=self.originalContent;
        }
    }
    else
    {
       if (self.note == nil)
       {
         if (self.textField.text.length > 0) {
         self.note = [[NMNote alloc] init];
       }
       self.note.content = self.textField.text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) if I have a plus button in the tableviewcontroller to create a new note, can't I say that if a segue preformed from the plus button it's a new note, and if it came from the cell selected button its not a new one? intend of the adding boolean? just asking @Paulw11

Comment: The "adding" is so you know what to do when the unwind segue triggers - if an add you need to add it to the array, if not then it is already in the array.  You could store the flag in your tableview controller rather than the create view controller, but having it in the create gives you the option of customising things in that view, such as having a button that says "add" or "save" according to the mode